# Reference request: Time-optimal trajectories

Tags: reference-request, optimization, optimal-control, optimal-transport

I am looking for some lecture notes or a textbook for time-optimal trajectories.

Any help is greatly appreciated. I am having plenty of trouble with understanding switching $C^+$ and $C^-$ curves.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One very good resource that is available for free online (legally, from the author's website) is Daniel Liberzon's book on calculus of variations and optimal control which you can find [here](http://liberzon.csl.illinois.edu/teaching/cvoc.pdf). On page $107$ of the book (which is page $117$ when you look at it in a PDF viewer), he solves an optimal control problem for a double integrator system subject to the constraint $u \in [-1,1]$. The switching curves are explicitly derived an then the principles of bang-bang control are discussed after that.

In addition, Bryson and Ho's optimal control book (it's not available for free, but [here](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0891162283) is a link to Amazon) goes over similar material, including deriving switching curves for a system known as the Bushaw oscillator (and these switching curves are actually what's pictured on the cover of the book).

Comment: The free resource looks really good so far. Thank you. I will check out Bryson and Ho when I can